# If $D=0$, then what are the necessary conditions for a set of linear equations in three variables to have a unique solution

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have three equations of the form:

a1* x+b1* y+c1* z+d1=0

a2* x+b2* y+c2* z+d2=0

a3* x+b3* y+c3* z+d3=0

what are the necessary conditions for them to have a unique solution if D=0.

I am referring to Cramer's rule, not Martin's rule.

Comment: @Amzoti meant z. corrected.

Comment: As I said in the deleted comment, in order to have a unique solution the determinant should not equal zero. Or, the rank of augumented matrix equals the rank of the coefficient matrix.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal no. If D=0, the system may or may not be inconsistent.

Comment: @Salena: I already gave you the condition which guarantees A UNQUE solution which is $D\neq 0$ or the other condition that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal But if D=0, then also there are possibilities of a UNIQUE solution.
And I am referring to Cramer's rule, not Martin's rule.

Comment: @Salena: Note that, there are three cases for your system, a UNIQE solution, an infinite number of solutions, or no solution.

Comment: This question seems to be wrongly asked: seeing the OP's response to Mhenni's comment *perhaps* the OP means conditions on some particular set of coefficients, up to and including the $\,d_i$'s . It also doesn't help the way the question's written...And what's $\,D\,$ : the coefficients' matrix's determinant or the augmented matrix's? This is odd...

Comment: Salena, if by $D$ you mean the determinant of the matrix of coefficients, then the system *can't* have a unique solution if $D=0$. It can't, because if it has one solution, then it has another solution where you add on to your first solution any non-zero solution of the system with $d_1=d_2=d_3=0$.

Comment: Yes got that. @MhenniBenghorbal thanks. It is clear now.

Comment: @Salena: You are welcome.

Comment: Salena, if you understand the solution to your problem, you should post an answer. It gives you good practice, and it helps stop the question from periodically popping back up on the front page.